# Guardar registros de cambios en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla llamada `productos`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que cada año los nombres de los productos o la descripción cambia, entonces solo un update no funciona ya que se requiere tener todo el historial de cambios y filtrarlos por años.

Existe tambien una tabla dependiente de la tabla productos llamado `venta_producto`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que opciones tengo para registrar los cambios anuales que se hacen?

Comment: Para el proximo año tambien tiene que tener el registro del último cambio automáticamente creado.

Comment: Quizá lo mejor sería programar un TRIGGER que te inserte en otra tabla aquellos datos de los que te interesa conservar un historial. En esa tabla habría una columna que sería la marca del tiempo que te ayudará a conservar el historial de actualizaciones.

Comment: ¿Necesitas un registro de auditoria de los cambios o quieres que los productos este "fechados"? Es decir, si pides un informe de un año para atrás ¿quieres ver los productos con el nombre actual o con el nombre que tenía hace un año?

Comment: @Patricio, con el nombre que tenía hace un año.

Comment: Ok,  podrías tener una tabla relacionada `ProductosNombresFechas`, con manera, con producto_id, fecha_desde y fecha_hasta (los tres campos serían la PK). El nombre actual o último activo sería el único que tendría fecha_hasta=NULL, cada vez que modifiques estos datos deberías: actualizar la fecha_hasta del último registro a la fecha del día e insertar un nuevo registro, con los nombres nuevos, con fecha_desde=hoy y fecha_hasta=null. Las consultas que necesiten el nombre por fecha deberán joinear con esta tabla y buscar si la fecha se encuentra comprendido en un desde / hasta.